# Tool to create Network Diagram

Tags: architecture, diagram

I am looking for a tool to build good looking network Diagram.
Right now i am just using images from google image search. But the diagrams doesnt look consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commercial options include [Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) on Windows, [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/) on Mac. for a free one take a look at [gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/uses/network-diagram-software/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want something that uses standardized diagramming techniques like UML you might be interested in Dia. It's a Gnome project, so it's available on Mac / Linux / Windows

http://live.gnome.org/Dia

Answer (score 1):

TechRepublic has written this very [useful article](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/diagram-your-network-with-these-tools/3352) linking to a number of tools, both open source and commercial.

Answer (score 1):

I normally use Visio to create network diagrams, although for pitches I actually use Microsoft Powerpoint (yes I know it sounds weird)!

I put a blog post together today to help people create better looking (but not quite as technical) network diagrams - perhaps worth a look: [Create beautiful 3D network diagrams in PowerPoint](https://www.azuz.it/article/create-beautiful-3d-network-diagrams-in-powerpoint)

Comment: ***404 error*** for link  `http://www.azuz.it/tutorials/create-beautiful-network-diagrams-in-powerpoint/`